# Doxygen doesn't parse tags normally. It parses tags like <Code>,<value> and \s\p into <computeroutput></computeroutput>

Tags: java, doxygen

I am trying to generate xml using doxygen from java sourcecode. Doxygen doesn't parse tags like
<code>,<value> and \s\p.... correctly. It generates xml with incorrect values.
For example:

```
    <code>0x0</code> tag is converted into    <computeroutput>0x0</computeroutput>.
    <para>
    <computeroutput>This is code tag</computeroutput>
    <value2>test value4</value2> </meta> </meta> <gid>000001</gid>    <read>1</read>
    </parameter> </component> </algebra>
    </para>
```

similarly for other tags like <value> and \s\p also. 
I am wondering why it happens????? 
Please let me know what are all other tags also will produce the same output
and how to resolve it.

Comment: What do you mean "doxygen doesn't parse tags ... correctly"? Why not - what do you expect to see and what do you actually see. If you want to include XML in your final documentation you should wrap it with the [`\verbatim`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdverbatim) and `\endverbatim` commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get \s\p in doxygen documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895981/how-to-get-s-p-in-doxygen-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

"correctly" is a bit of a misnomer when referring to xml, unless it weren't structured correctly, but I think you're referring to the tags. 
If you don't like the output from doxygen why not write an xslt to make it whatever you want? I'm sure there are many doxygen.xml --> myflavor.xml transforms out there that you could use as a starting point.